# is it possible to do a text.contain with multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

If i have a code like this

```
reference = List.Buffer(#"table1"[Keywords]),
    Custom1 = #"Renamed Columns3",
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(Custom1, "Custom", each [ccenter] & " " & [vnumber] & " " & [Line Description]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Taxonomy Reference", each List.Select(
    reference,
    (Taxonomy_Reference)=> Text.Contains([Custom],Taxonomy_Reference))),
    #"Expanded Vendors" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Taxonomy Reference"),
```

What this code is doing is from table1, it's making a list out of a column and then in added custom - its doing a text.contain comparison between keywords column of table 1 with the custom column of table 2. This is working fine - however i want to refine it further by doing a comparison between vnumber and ccenter (common in both tables) **first** and only if ccenter and vnumber are same then do a keyword and line description comparison for those vnumbers and ccenters.

Comment: You could create a Joined table (with `JoinKind.Inner`) with those two columns as the key

Comment: any chance you can provide sample data and desired output?

Comment: @smpa01 sure, i will paste it here